# PHP Sessions not working

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-cookies

This time, I need your help in something related to php. My users script is not working as expected, it's supposed to keep logged in 3 weeks but this just fails, after less than 60 minutes the session is destroyed and I need to login again, any suggestion?

My code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); 

mysql_connect("YOU", "DONT", "NEED") or die("database connection failed");
mysql_select_db("THIS!!!") or die("database selection failed");

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$remember = $_POST['remember'];

$token = $_POST['login-token'];
$error;

        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            $error = $error." :erlgd:";
        }
        if(empty($user)){
            $error = $error." :erusr:";
        }
        if(empty($pass)){
            $error = $error." :erpwd:";
        } else
        $password = md5($pass);

        if(empty($error)){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$password'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($count == 0){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_users WHERE email='$user' AND password='$password'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                if($count == 0){
                    $error = $error.":erwrg:";
                }
            }

        }


    // Once everything's filled out


        // Just double check there are no errors first
        if($error == '') {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $minutes = 10080;

                if($minutes == 0)
                    ini_set('sesion.cookie_lifetime', 0);
                else
                    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * $minutes);
                session_regenerate_id();

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_activate WHERE username='$user'";
                $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
                if ($count > 0)
                    $_SESSION['activate'] = 1;
                else
                    $_SESSION['activate'] = 0;

                $_SESSION['restricted'] = $row['restricted'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                $user_level = unserialize($row['user_level']);
                $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
                $sql = "SELECT level_disabled FROM login_levels WHERE level_level = '$user_level'";
                $disRow =  mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
                $_SESSION['level_disabled'] = $disRow['level_disabled'];

                if(!empty($remember)) {
                    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60*60*24*100); // Set to expire in 3 months & 10 days
                    session_regenerate_id();
}
                // And our magic happens here ! Let's sign them in
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

                unset($_SESSION['token']);
                echo "success";
                // Redirect after it's all said and done

            }

        }else{
            echo "error:".$error;
        }



?>
```

Thanks!

PS: As additional data, this is a shared server.

Comment: why would you do this code in a while loop?

Comment: @dqhendricks in a loop? I'm sorry but there isn't a loop, maybe you say this because it first searches if it's an user and later searches if it is a e-mail.

Comment: no i am talking about this line... `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {`

Comment: are you expecting more than one record to be returned? why is this in a loop?

Comment: @dqhendricks not really, but don't know how to change it and dont alter the other pieces of code, also I dont see any problem to keep it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `session.gc_maxlifetime` in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Either update it there, or try putting `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*24*7*3);` in your script at the top

Increase that to something larger

basically, this is how long the server waits before clearing session files

Comment: Shared hosting, any suggestion?

Comment: you could try running `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*24*7*3);`

Comment: or ask your hosting provider to change that value

Comment: This seems to work, please update answer and wait until tomorrow, I will see if this fixes it. thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to see if the cookies and sessions were set successfully AFTER logged in? Like a sessions historial in the browser?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this route. Sessions aren't meant to be overly persistent. Otherwise your filesystem (or database) end up with hundreds or thousands of stale sessions which won't be reaped for weeks or months.

Comment: @MikePurcell Not necessarily true. Depends on how you are using sessions. And it wouldnt be terribly hard to set up PDO sessions on a shared host. It also depends on how much traffic he's planning on getting. One good way to check Luis, is look at the expire time on the cookie, in your browser management

Comment: @MikePurcell realized i zoned out while reading your message. But still stands, that it depends on how much traffic the OP is intending to get.

Comment: @Ascherer: I agree. However this solution will not scale well. If he ends up clustering servers to serve and handle requests (and associated sessions), and the session handler is still default (files), then serverA which originated the session will save the session, but serverB may handle the request 3 weeks later and save the same session. Basically, there is no guarantee that stale session will be recycled.

Comment: Then go towards a PDO session and scale there?

Comment: @Ascherer: Ya, if he implemented database as the session handler, then at least he wouldn't have to worry about duplicate stale sessions. Definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use cookies to support the `remember me` type of behavior. When a session is destroyed on the server, the cookie is meant to act as a catalyst to start a new session as the same user, when they re-visit your site, and auto-logging them in, behind the scenes.

A Google search returns some pretty good results, most notably a [reference](http://www.bitrepository.com/php-autologin.html) to actual cookie code (search for autologin.php).

Comment: @Ascherer, I did and it seems to work kinda better, going to wait for results.

Comment: Mike, thanks! I didn't know this, I thought cookies and sessions were the same, now working with this, waiting for tomorrow to accept the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to see if the cookies and sessions were set successfully AFTER logged in? Like a sessions historial in the browser?

Comment: You can refer to `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` as you can normal arrays. For example, in one of my projects I have `$_COOKIE[$cookiePrefix . '_password']` which I use to check to see if cookie has been set matching 'wx_password'. Read up on the docs related to cookies and you will see how it easy it is. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @Luis: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

usually people use session_set_cookie_params() to change the lifetime of a session cookie. and you should be setting this before the first session_start() is called I believe. the default is typically set to 0 (aka when the user closes the browser window).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

you will also need to change the garbage collection max lifetime for session files. before your session begins, try:

```
ini_set(’session.gc_maxlifetime’, $lifetime_in_seconds);
```

Comment: Is there a way to see if the cookies and sessions were set successfully AFTER logged in? Like a sessions historial in the browser?